# Python OpenCV difficulty reading large QR code

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I'm trying to read the following large qr code with OpenCV in python

[image: Qr code with a 6x6 array of anchor points]

first I load the image:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("qrgame.png")
```

Then, I determine the bounding box for the qr:

```
detect = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
shouldBeTrue, points = detect.detect(img)
assert shouldBeTrue
```

the assertion passes, but when I go to decode the qr, by running:

```
detect.decode(img, points)
```

it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-k8sx3e60\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 41209000000 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'
```

Comment: you may recognize this qr from a certain [youtube video](https://youtu.be/9_gdOKSTaxM)

Comment: maybe `QR` is incorrect or it is too small and code recognizes it incorrectly - so it may get wrong value which try to reserve too much memory. Code works with some other small `QR` codes - like in [OpenCV QR Code Scanner ( C++ and Python )](https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-qr-code-scanner-c-and-python/). This article also mentions module `zbar` and maybe it will works better with your `QR`

Comment: I can't identify the code, too. I guess it is wrong or not clear enough